# Создание заметок на чистом PHP, без использования sql или внешнего файла

Tags: php

Здрасте, мне сегодня дали задание, сделать заметки без использования sql или внешних файлов, с возможностью редактирования статуса и удалением записи, всегда делал такое с помощью mysql. Можете помочь, как это можно реализовать, так как я вообще не понимаю, как это сделать, с возможность редактирования и удаления конкретной записи?
Цитирую задание:

> Инструменты: PHP/HTML
> Важное примечание: Не использовать хранение данных в Базе данных или файлах.
> Кнопка Remove All - очищает весь список заданий из второго блока. Все элементы удаляются.
> Кнопка Ready All - все задания в списке отмечаются выполненными. У всех заданий меняется статус "Не готово" на "Выполнен"
> Описание задания
> Кнопка READY - меняет статус задания с "Не готово" на "Выполнено"
> Кнопка UNREADY - меняет статус задания с "Выполнено" на "Не готово"
> Кнопка DELETE - удаляет блок с текущим заданием из списка.
> Статус - содержит текущий статус задания. "Выполнено" или "Не готово"

Comment: Какая-то ересь, кроме сессий ничего не приходит в голову. Можно конечно еще на клиенте юзать localstorage, но так и php вообще не нужен.

Comment: Тоже, честно, я весь день ломаю голову, как вообще это возможно сделать без sql, думал с помощью cookie можно провернуть эту штуку, но в итоге споткнулся об то, что можно создавать бесконечно много заметок, а как их добавлять через куки, хз.

Comment: Если необходимо, я могу дать весь текст задания.

Comment: ну для задания можно писать в куки. еще можно писать в хтмл файл и парсить его же. формально это не файл данных. но вообще я бы нарисовал им фак, вздохнул с облегчением, и поискал бы  другое место

Comment: @u_mulder даже если речь идет про сессии, то это по факту тоже использование файлов (ну если ничего не менять), так что нет. 
 :)

Comment: Похоже человек задающий подобные задачи - чутка улыбается. 
Вы не сможете по факту при данном стеке не использовать файлы т.к. очевидно речь идет о том что вы должны использовать cookies, без этого вы не сможете сделать ничего. 
Можно объяснить ему что cookies использует файлы и по факту это  тоже нарушение. Этим затупить его можно без проблем :)

А почему у вас не получается через cookies добавить и работать с нужными вам данными - это вы подумайте еще раз, очевидно что это можно сделать.